# Angularjs: custom angular filter leads to infinite loop

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my Ionic app, I created a custom filter, 'partition', in my filter.js file (see below).

I am trying to use it like this in the template, but I get a rootscope error:
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3…inder%20Max%20-%20Keely%20Andrew%5C%22%3B%20oldVal%3A%20undefined%22%5D%5D

Can you please help me fix this ?

Thanks

template result.html :

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="true" does-continue="true" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
            <ion-slide ng-repeat="batch in prodata | partition:8 track by $index">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="item in batch track by $index">
                        <a class="suggestPro" href="#">
                            <span><img ng-src="img/boards/{{item.imageName}}" /></span>
                            <p class="flex-caption"> {{item.model}} - {{item.name}}</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
```

app.js :

```
angular.module('BoardLine', ['ionic', 'ngCookies', 'ui.unique', 'BoardLine.controllers', 'BoardLine.services', 'BoardLine.filters'])
```

filter.js :

```
angular.module('BoardLine.filters', [])

.filter('nospace', function() {
    return function (value) {
        return (!value) ? '' : value.replace(/ /g, '');
    };
})

.filter('partition', function() {
    return function(array, size) {
        var newArray = [], i, next;

        for(i = 0; i < array.length; i = next) {
            next = i + size;
            newArray.push(array.slice(i, next));
        }

        return newArray;
    };
});
```

Comment: @PankajParkar `track by` has to go after filters

Comment: @Emre the error is just before the page shows, in the console : Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3…5C%5Ct%5C%5Ct%20%20%20%20%5C%5Ct%5C%22%3B%20oldVal%3A%20undefined%22%5D%5D

Comment: If you follow the link in the error, it says there is an infinite loop in your code. You might want to examine your 2 ng-repeats

Comment: Ok thanks, if you look at my two ng-repeats it doesn't seem like there is an infinite loop

Comment: @Emre can you please help me further, I think the infinite loop comes from the way the filter is coded...

Comment: I am not sure but maybe the problem is in the usage of i = next and next = i + size

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to achieve this result, without the 'partition' filter, and with the use of `limitTo` :

```
    <ion-slide-box show-pager="true" does-continue="true" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="s in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in prodata | matchingProBrand:computed.proName:computed.proBrand | limitTo:s*8+8  | limitTo:-8">
                    <a class="suggestPro" ng-click="launchComputeService(item.id)">
                        <span><img ng-src={{imagesUrls[item.imageName]}} /></span>
                        <p class="flex-caption"> {{item.model}} - {{item.name}}</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </ion-slide>

    </ion-slide-box>
```